# How to save a file with phonegap and find that file in Windows file system

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I would like to save a file "readme.txt" inside my iphone with phonegap for logging pourpuses, I have tried to do the example provided by [phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter):

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

everything seems to work just fine, my question is where can I find this file within the Windows File system?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the Mac filesystem, and that you actually want to download the file you created.
If so, then this is what you should do:
1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac.
2. Open XCode's Organizer.
3. you'll see your iPhone in the "Devices" tab, on the left panel. Now, click "Applications".
4. Select your application and click the "Download" arrow at the bottom.
5. Type the desired file name and select the desired target directory.
6. Your application (and its related files) will now be saved in the target directory as a *.xcappdata file. Right-click this file and select "Show Package Contents".
7. A Finder window will be opened, displaying a directory called "AppData". Open this directory, then open its inner directory "Documents". You should find your log file at this path.

Comment: No I really meant Windows File System, So there is no way to explore my iphone in Windows apart from the Pictures?

Comment: Not without installing [an additional file browser](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=browse+iphone+in+windows&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=kcdNUubHGcWB4ASx_4C4Dw)